# how to pass a optional param into spring controller and jpql query

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data

this is my repository:

```
@Query( "SELECT new com.app.gsc.entities.ListeBI(lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,count(*) as totalNumber,lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) from ListeDeControleDetailsMission lm where lm.boolDepart=false OR lm.ficheDeMission.codeDeFicheDeMission=:CodeMission GROUP BY lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,DATE(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)" )
List<ListeBI> getIncidentDepart( @Param( "CodeMission" ) Integer missId );
```

and heres my controller :

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "admin/dashboard/getIncidentDepart/{codeMission}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public Reponse getIncidentDepart( HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable Integer codeMission ) { // entêtes
    CorsController.getIncidentDepart( response, codeMission );
    if ( messages != null ) {
        return new Reponse( -1, messages );
    }
    List<ListeBI> listeBIs = null;
    try {
        listeBIs = application.getIncidentDepart( codeMission );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        return new Reponse( 5, Static.getErreursForException( e ) );
    }
    return new Reponse( 0, Static.getMapForMissionIncidents( listeBIs ) );
}
```

My problems are: this first problem i want to pass the codeMission as choosen variable, i dont how i can put that but i will explain, if i passe the codeMission variable in the controller the request should work, and if i dont passe the codeMission variable in the controlle the request also should work, how i can do that please, and also i'm not sure if the condition in the request works level is fine:

> where lm.boolDepart=false OR lm.ficheDeMission.codeDeFicheDeMission=:CodeMission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About JPQL question**

Here :

```
where lm.boolDepart=false OR lm.ficheDeMission.codeDeFicheDeMission=:CodeMission
```

If your `:CodeMission` param is `not null` valued, your filter works as expected but if it has `null` value, it filters on `:codeMission==null` condition and it is not what you wish.

To address both cases (`null :CodeMission` param  and `not null :CodeMission` param) , try that :

```
where lm.boolDepart=false OR 
      (:CodeMission is null OR lm.ficheDeMission.codeDeFicheDeMission=:CodeMission)
```

Concretely :

If it is filled with for example `100` as value for `:CodeMission`, it results in :

```
where lm.boolDepart=false OR 
      (lm.ficheDeMission.codeDeFicheDeMission=:100)
```

If it is filled with `null` as value for `:CodeMission`, it results in  :

```
where lm.boolDepart=false OR 
      (null is null)
```

---

**About Rest configuration question**

If you use Spring 4 and Java 8, you can make `codeMission` optional :

```
@RequestMapping( value = "admin/dashboard/getIncidentDepart/{codeMission}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public Reponse getIncidentDepart( HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable Optional<Integer> codeMission ) {
...
}
```

Otherwise, create two methods with two distinct paths.